# ios8 calls - (void) onKeyboardShow:(NSNotification *)notification two times

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios8

We have a screen with a UITextField and a UITextView.

When I tap on any of those the method:

```
- (void) onKeyboardShow:(NSNotification *)notification
```

gets called.

The UITextField has .autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo; while the UITextView has the autocrrectionType in yes.

I have the following code on the onKeyboardShow:

```
CGSize keyboardSize = [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

I am experiencing two problems:

1. The method is being called even if the keyboard is already on the screen and you tap from one field to the other. This in iOS7 didn't happen.
2. The height is the same in both calls not taking into consideration the suggestions bar in one vs the other one.
   For UITextView the height is: 253 for the UITextField is 216. But if the user first taps on the text field he gets the 216 and then when tapping the UITextView again the size is 216. If it is done in different order I get the 253 for both.

Has anyone experience the same? Is this expected? Do I have to check which field was the one that triggered the onKeyboardShow in order to adapt my UI for one height and another and hardcode the height of the suggestion bar? Can i get the height of the suggestion bar from the NSNotification?

Thanks for any help

Comment: I've experienced the same thing. I think it might be due to the fact that in iOS8, keyboards have dynamic heights. (Custom keyboards can have custom heights!) Also, each text field can require a different kind of keyboard - email, number pad, etc. I think the callback is happening on text field changes in order to provide the most recent keyboard information.

Comment: Number 1. If both the textfield and textview have the autocorrection set to NO the onKeyboardShow only ocurs once.
Number 2. I did not find a way to get this information. I guess it might be a UIKeyboardAdtionalFrameHeight (?)

Comment: Your first point is really interesting! Sounds like it's that extra bar at the top for QuickType. There is also `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification` that you might look into. As for one of your questions, I think that the height of the keyboard DOES include the suggestion bar. So it's just one number.

Answer (score 0):

Answer in parts.

1. I tried replicating your first problem and could. The reason the notifications get called is because when you have a keyboard with autocorrect on, it has a top bar of suggestions. When you switch between textfields it has to animate the top bar in and out. The notifications will provide the most up-to-date keyboard frame.

This little bugger pops up if the textfield as autocorrect on. Pops down (out of the frame) if autocorrect is off.

[image: Tiny keyboard bar]

2. You shouldn't have to figure out which field is currently selected to properly handle the keyboard. Even the exact heights don't matter. (You should never hard code keyboard heights.)

I saw that you were using UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey.
I suggest using UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey.

This worked for me:

```
- (void)keyboardShown:(NSNotification *)note {
    CGRect keyboardRect = [[[note userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
    self.customConstraint.constant = -keyboardRect.size.height - 20;
}
```

Note: the constraint just pinned my custom view to the bottom. So when the keyboard shows, it just offsets the constraint by the proper amount. 
Not the best solution. I'm not sure why I have to have the -20 to make it work, but I'll keep digging.